# Book preview possible with TexStudio?

Tags: texstudio, viewers

By default TexStudio's preview window shows all pages in a single column. Is there a setting to make it show 2 pages side by side? Ideal would be a book preview just like offered by Sumatra PDF viewer.

I cannot find any according option nor setting. However, I'd like to make sure that I did not miss anything!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible  if you pop out the viewer. After doing this you see a new menu  bar. 
[image]

This one offers <kbd>View</kbd> -> <kbd>Grid</kbd>. If you choose <kbd>2x1</kbd> you get a booklike preview. Make sure <kbd>Single Page Step</kbd> is unchecked, to  get proper scrolling.

[image]

Comment: And can it show animations? Or only Acrobat can?